# Any instance where DMV can cause blocking?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dmv

So we had some slow performance with timeouts this morning.  When looking for the cause, our blocking query (uses DMVs) showed up as the blocking query.  I think this was just a fluke but the job we use to get the blocking details was running 4 to 5 times slower than normal.  I believe this is just a side effect of whatever was causing the timeouts.

So my question is whether querying the DMVs could actually cause blocking for queries on other tables?  Doesn't seem logical.

Using:

```
dm_exec_sql_text
dm_os_waiting_tasks
dm_tran_locks
dm_exec_sessions
dm_exec_requests
```

Comment: I've seen several people report that some of these DMVs can cause blocking. They will often suggest you use READ UNCOMMITTED (NOLOCK) against them - which is a much less egregious thing than doing that against real data.